# How to tell Python to use local name rather than global one?

Tags: python, scope

<s>For some reason I need to use `locals()` explicitly to assign values to some variables; but I would like to reference those variables directly later. The example below explains what I'm thinking about:</s>

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def hello():
   local = locals()
   c = 1
   for i in ['x', 'y', 'z']:
       local[i] = c
       c += 1
   print(x)

hello()
```

However it is incorrect, with the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ttt.py", line 11, in <module>
    hello()
  File "./ttt.py", line 9, in hello
    print(x)
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

Seems that Python would look the *global* 'x' rather than the *local* one. Surely I can use `print(local['x'])` at Line 9, but is there *another* way?

#### update:

What I really need is to "automatically" create several variables related to *a list of strings*: each of these variables' **name** and **value** are a transformation of one string in the list.
For example,

```
# given
list_of_string = ['clang', 'scan-build']
# I hope to create two variables:
clang = '/usr/bin/clang'
scan_build = '/usr/local/bin/scan-build'
```

Here the **name** of the variables (*clang*, *scan_build*) is the string in `list_of_string` except that '-' is replaced with '_', and the **value** is the really location of the string (generated by some function works as unix `which`).

Comment: You cannot assign to `locals()`; this is documented behaviour. It reflects local names in *one direction only*.

Comment: [Why would you want to do that?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) Can you give more context?

Comment: The question here is then: *What are you trying to do*? You cannot and should not create variables dynamically like this.

Comment: Your update doesn't really answer the question, what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MartijnPieters just updated a bit.

Comment: @HongxuChen: so why not just use a dictionary instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was thinking the way I used was permitted. Didn't notice that it's better to use dictionary for the name and value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mess with `locals`. Use a dictionary:

```
import subprocess

list_of_strings = ['clang', 'no-name', 'xml2-config']

d={}
for s in list_of_strings:
    try:
        rtr=subprocess.check_output(['which',s])
        d[s.replace('-','_')]=rtr.rstrip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print '"{}" not found'.format(s)

print d
```

Prints (on OS X):

```
"no-name" not found
{'clang': '/usr/bin/clang', 'xml2_config': '/usr/bin/xml2-config'}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs about the dictionary returned by `locals()`

> **Note**:
>
> The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could use `eval` but I would find another way to do what you want:

```
print(eval("x"))
```

Also `local = locals()` stores a reference to itself in locals.

If you want to store variables dynamically just use a normal dict and access by key:

```
def hello():
    local = {}
    c = 1
    for i in ['x', 'y', 'z']:
        local[i] = c
        c += 1
    print(local["x"])
    print(local["y"])
    print(local["z"])
hello()
1
2
3
```

If you need to share the variables amongst other functions just return the dict add pass the returned value to the other functions.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign to local variables dynamically. As you don't write your actual use case, I can only give a common use case: you have some dictionary with default values:

```
def hello(values):
    x = values.get('x', 1)
    y = values.get('y', 2)
    z = values.get('z', 3)
    print(x)
```